# Blender Vertices Merge Problem

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am a using Blender version 2.82 on Windows 10. I'm following this tutorial on
YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHv4VDoCwYc at 28:00 where he merges 2 vertices. However when I try it, it turns out like this:

[image: This is the result when I merge the 2 points on the right side]

Comment: It looks as if you made an edge.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

He is definitely doing it right in the tutorial so the problem lies somewhere in the part you have not revealed any information about - in something that you did differently. The thing to do here would be to redo it all again until it works carefully tracking and keeping all your actions in mind. This is how tutorials should usually be approached.

*I guess*, you may have double geometry and when you select the vertices, some overlapping vertices remain unselected. You could try to redo the whole part from start or select all and merge vertices by distance first.